# How to set Validations along with DisplayStartDate

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I current have 2 controls. The first control is a DatePicker named DisbursalDatePicker, the second control is a grid which has multiple columns. The only column that matters is the date column. When dates are changed, there's a validation check to determine if row.date is before DisbursalDatePicker, if it is then display a validation error.

The validation works perfect and when there's no errors. The displaystartdate is working correctly for gridrows. But if there's a validation error, for some reason the displaystartdate is set to the current selecteddate of the row instead of the DisbursalDatePicker.

```
private void DisbursalDatePicker_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ScriptDTO script in RadGridView1.Items.OfType<ScriptDTO>())
    {
        if (script.Date <= DisbursalDatePicker.SelectedDate)
        {
            script.SetError("Date", "Must be after disbursal");
        }
        else
        {
            script.ClearErrors();
        }
    }
}
```

Script DTO

```
public class ScriptDTO : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
    ...
    private DateTime _date;
    public DateTime Date
    {
        get { return _date; }
        set { _date = value; OnPropertyChanged("Date"); }
    }

    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> errors = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public void ClearErrors()
    {
        this.errors.Clear();
    }

    public void SetError(string propertyName, string error)
    {
        string currentPropertyError;
        if (this.errors.TryGetValue(propertyName, out currentPropertyError))
        {
            this.errors.Remove(propertyName);
        }

        this.errors.Add(propertyName, error);
        this.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }

    public string GetError(string propertyName)
    {
        string result;
        if (this.errors.TryGetValue(propertyName, out result))
        {
            return result;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetError(columnName);
        }
    }

    public string Error
    {
        get
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

View

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Date" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Date, StringFormat=d}">
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Date}" DisplayDateStart="{Binding StartDate, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn>

foreach (var script in ScheduleScripts)
{
    script.StartDate = DisbursalDate;
}
```

Comment: Is it the StartDate property that returns the wrong date or what is your issue? Where do you set this property?

Comment: Hi @mm8 Sample scenario, my grid has 1 row with the date value of February 1st. If I change my DisbursalDatePicker to be March 1st, The row won't pass validation and when I try to change the date the DisplayStartDate is February 1st instead of being March 1st. The code to set the start date is now available.